# Does redux middleware need to "return" next or is it implicit?

Tags: redux, middleware

I have a bit of code, which looks something like this

```
export default function fooMiddleware({ dispatch, getState }) {
  return next => action => {
    if (type === TYPES.REGISTER_FOO_INITIALIZED) {
      next(action); // return next?
    }

    if (someOtherCondition) {
        dispatch(ACTIONS.loadDates());
      }
    }

    next(action);
  };
}
```

Do I need to explicitly have the `next` functions (namely the first one) `return` or does that not matter in this case.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not implicit.  This is just a normal function.  If you don't actually `return` anything, it's the same as `return undefined`.

A good Redux middleware *should* always return the result of `next(action)` unless it is specifically trying to override the return value and substitute something else (or is intercepting the action and not passing it on at all).  Otherwise, a later middleware that *is* trying to return something will never have that value be returned as intended.